# Ember.js compliant way to access custom data structure in localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ember.js

Our current project is to build a browser extension with a content script wich records and stores data into the browser extensions localStorage and a popup window which renders the recorded data to the user.

Right now the content script is ready. For the popup window I would like to utilize emberjs. It's already set up and renders some data. My problem right now is that most of the ember tutorials are using ember-data to abstract CRUD operations but this would't fit our data structure.

Is there an "ember compliant" way to modify the extensions localStorage which updates the model and also the view?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard built into ember for doing this.

I'd recommend using Ember Data and extending the Local Storage adapter to follow your specific workflow.